# Replacing single quotes with double quotes in SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am creating a vulnerable Windows Forms application using C# to practise SQL Injection and understand why this vulnerability happens in the first place. I am aware that I should be using parameterised queries to develop a secure application.

The application requires a user to enter their username and password in order to login. The following code is responsible for dynamically generating an SQL query based on user’s input:

```
public SqlDataReader performLogin(String username_input, String password_input)
{
    String username = username_input;
    String password = password_input;

    String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'";

    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

    SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

    return reader;
}
```

The SQL Server database contains a username called ‘admin’, and I can login as that user without knowing their password by entering the following data in the username field:

```
admin'--
```

However, I would like to modify the dynamically generated SQL query so that I would have to enter double quotes (not two single quotes) instead of one single quote in order to login as admin:

```
admin"--
```

I’ve tried replacing every double quote character with a single quote and every single quote with double quotes. I’ve also tried replacing every single quote character with double quotes and escaping them as follows:

```
String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users where username=\"" + username + "\" and password=\"" + password + "\"";

String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users where username=@"" + username + "@" and password=@"" + password + "@"";
```

I've not been able to find a working solution yet. I either get syntax errors or the application crashes after I attempt to login.

Comment: You cannot use double quote for strings in SQL query. Unless you set `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`

Comment: You say you want to “practise SQL Injection” then say “I would like to ... enter double quotes ... to login as admin”? [Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) That is not SQL injection so what do you think that will accomplish?

Comment: Using double quotes is a valid method of bypassing a very common SQL injection mitigation technique - blacklisting the single quote character. Developers may use double quotes instead of single quotes in their dynamic SQL queries thinking their code is secure. I just wanted to see how I would be able to implement that in C#. Thanks for pointing to that XY problem, it's an interesting read, my question was most likely not very clear, sorry.

Comment: For other people looking at this question (who don't waant to be open to SQL Injection) https://bertwagner.com/2017/09/12/how-unicode-homoglyphs-can-thwart-your-database-security/ may be worth a read. The approach being used in this question is very dangerous. It should not be used.

Comment: Whose server are you practicing on? With all the things to learn, this is one you can take on faith and move on.

Comment: My own SQL Server 2008, running on a Windows 7 VM on my own internal network not exposed to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just replace the username before passing it onto the query?

```
string finalUsername = username.Contains("\"") ? username.Replace("\"", "'") : username;
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users where username='" + finalUsername + "' and password='" + password + "'";
```

If you wanted, you could even prevent the original vector:

```
string finalUsername = username.Contains("\"") ? username.Replace("\"", "'") : (username.Contains("'") ? username.Replace("'", "") : username);
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users where username='" + finalUsername + "' and password='" + password + "'";
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted